# How to connect to mysql localhost database with a different computer

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

i have a laptop and a desktop, i saved all the database information on the desktop, is there anyway i can connect to the desktop sql database while working with the laptop? this is what i have tried on the laptop

```
define("DB_SERVER", "192.0.0.45");     //desktop ip (made up)
define("DB_USER", "root");            //desktop database usr
define("DB_PASS", "");               //desktop database password
define("DB_NAME", "scroll");         //desktop database name
```

i use this 192.0.0.45 to access the files in the desktop localhost eg(192.0.0.45/page) and it works

Answer (score 2):

In your httpd.conf find `Listen 127.0.0.1:80` and replace it with `Listen 80` or `Listen *:80`. Now find `Allow from 127.0.0.1` and change it to `Allow from all`. Now you can access the localhost on your desktop machine via your IPv4 ip. You can find it by typing in `ipconfig` for windows `ifconfig` on Linux. You must type in the ip address of your desktop machine. You can find many related stuff on stackexchange community like serverfault.com or superuser.com.

Answer (score 2):

make sure the desktop and the laptop are in same network the go to your browser and enter 
192.0.0.45/phpmyadmin
if the port is 80
else 192.0.0.45:'port_no'/phpmyadmin
without qoutes

Comment: the 192.0.0.45/phpmyadmin worked but how do i connect it with this define("DB_SERVER", "192.0.0.45");

Answer (score 1):

your local installation of MySQL should be locked down to be accessed from `localhost` by default **for security reasons**.

In order to access your db from another machine you need to unlock this setting.
With tools like MAMP Pro you have an GUI that helps you in configuring this setting:

[image]

To practically configure your local MySQL please refer to this StackOverflow thread:
[MySQL can connect locally but not remotely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765783/mysql-can-connect-locally-but-not-remotely?rq=1)

IMPORTANT: this option will **create a security issue** on your machine, I suggest to open up MySQL only during development sessions and then **close it up as quick as you can**. Especially if you plan to to this on an Internet accessible machine!